# Countdown script called via a function do not work

Tags: javascript, timer, setinterval, countdown

I'm new to javascript and not a programmer so my question could be stupid, but I can't find a way out of this problem.
I use a countdown function that is working properly when called with body onload, but I have to use others scripts in the same page so I have to make it work in a function called via div id. So I put that script in a function, but it does not seem to work.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<script>
<?php
echo "var now = new Date(\"$time_fr_js\").getTime();";
echo "var countDownDate = new Date(\"$time_fr_target_js\").getTime();";
?>
function times() {
  (countdown);
  setInterval(otherfunction1, 1000);
  setInterval(otherfunction2, 1000);
}
function countdown() {
  var x = setInterval(function() {';
  var distance = countDownDate - now;
  var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
  var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
  document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = hours + ":"
  + minutes + ":" + seconds;
  if (distance < 0) {
    clearInterval(x);
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "<font color=red>countdown timeout</font>";
  }
 }, 1000);
</script>

<body onload="times()">
<div id="count"></div>
some html here
<div id="otherfunction1"></div>
<div id="otherfunction2"></div>
```

Comment: This just looks like a typo. You never call `countdown`. `(countdown);` should be `countdown();`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Ineed it is a typo. I tried a few different things so I messed up a bit.I put back everything with "countdown", but it is not working. None of the functions loads at all. If i remove the var x = setInterval(function() part, countdown function is still not working but others functions load properly. The problem seems to be related to the usage of setInterval inside a function called by another function ?

Comment: This shouldn't even run now that I've looked over it again. You're getting errors in your console that you've ignored. `function() {';` isn't legal afaik. Please fix typos, and adjust the indentation so it's clear what the code is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I'm working on it. Thanks for pointed out that.

Comment: the function(); part seems legal. I used the example at https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_countdown.asp . What I'm trying to do is puting that script inside a function.

Comment: `function(){';}` isn't legal though, and that's what you have on the line I pointed out.

Comment: Corrected. Now this line is "var x = setInterval(function() {". No more errors on console, and other functions properly load. but countdown function is not loading.

Comment: Seems to work if I call the function with   setInterval(countdown, 1000);. Not sure how it will work with setinterval on function call + inside the function itself.

Comment: It print the cooldown but it doesn't refresh. I'll try to mess with setinterval.

Answer (score 0):

So I've made a few modifications to your code, I did have to ignore `otherfunction1` and `otherfunction2` since they didn't seem important for your countdown questions. See the modified code below:

```js
var countDownDate = new Date("2018-05-26T15:48:00.000Z").getTime(); // Just use your own end time here
function times() {
  countdown();
}

function countdown() {
  var cd_interval = setInterval(function() {
    var now = new Date().getTime(); // Moved now inside the countdown function since it need to be validated with the current time
    var distance = countDownDate - now;
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
    if (distance < 0) {
      clearInterval(cd_interval);
      document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "<font color=red>countdown timeout</font>";
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<body onload="times()">
  <div id="count"></div>
  some html here
  <div id="otherfunction1"></div>
  <div id="otherfunction2"></div>
</body>
```

I've added some comments just in case some of them did not make sense.

Comment: It's working great. Thanks a lot, I've learned useful things today!

Comment: Sure, would be great if you could make the answer if you found it correct. Thanks! Let me know if you have additional questions as well.